# Hot/Cold water lines not set in between studs Tub/shower removal

Tags: water, concrete, shower, foundation, bathtub

I removed a tub/shower insert and noticed the hot/cold lines are not set in between the studs, how can I tile around them? I don't have a plumber available. [image: behind tub insert]

Comment: Are you intending to turn this space into a tiled shower?

Comment: The vent pipe seems to be the problem.  If comfortable with losing about 3/4 inch floor space, then adding 1x2 or 1x3s to the wall should be enough to miss the pipes.

Comment: What are you putting back in place of the tub/shower?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fur out the studs with furring strips so that you can install cement backer board evenly.

Be careful when screwing board into that corner so that you don't hit those water lines.